# Check if optional array contains element and display view

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I'm fetching objects via API into an optional array.  In a view, I'm then trying to determine if that array contains a set of possible elements when the view is loaded.

If the array contains that element, I'll show a separate view for it.  If it doesn't I won't show it.

**How do I check if that optional array contains a specific element?**

So for example, I want to check if projectType.landscapes? contains a "mulching" entry.  Also, the ProjectType.Landscapes.types array will contain string values that correspond to the present projectType.landscape options, for example, ["mulching", "clearing", "treeCare"] or simply ["mulching"].

Here's my data structure:

```
// MARK: - ProjectType
struct ProjectType: Codable {
    let landscapes: [Landscape]?
    let generalConstructions: [GeneralConstruction]?
}
// MARK: - GeneralConstruction
struct GeneralConstruction: Codable {
    let id: Int
}

// MARK: - Landscape
struct Landscape: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let types: [String]
    let mulching: Mulching?
    let clearing: Clearing?
    let planting: Planting?
    let treeCare: TreeCare?
    let other: Other?
}

// MARK: - Clearing
struct Clearing: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let clearingArea, removeTrees, treeCount, approxTreeHeight: String
    let treeStumps: String
}

// MARK: - Mulching
struct Mulching: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let mulchingType, currentlyInPlace, currentlyInPlaceCustom, roomLength: String
    let roomWidth, color, customColor, length: String
    let approximateLength: String
}

// MARK: - Other
struct Other: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let otherDetails: String
}

// MARK: - Planting
struct Planting: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let designPlan, treeLargerThanFiveFeet, plantCount: String
}

// MARK: - TreeCare
struct TreeCare: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let careDescription: String
}
```

Here's where I'd check to see if the landscape types are present:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandscapeSpecificsView: View {
    
    let projectType: ProjectType
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Here is the landscape specific project info.  I'll show mulching or clearing, or treeCare, etc.")
        }
        
    }
}

struct MulchingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Here is the mulching info")
    }
}

struct ClearingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Here is the clearing info")
    }
}

struct PlantingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Here is the planting info")
    }
}

struct TreeCareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Here is the treecare info")
    }
}

struct LandscapeOtherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Here is the landscape other info")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear still. The way you ask if an array contains an element is with (get ready for it) `contains`. What's the issue?

Comment: @matt I can't get it to work using contains.  It's an array in an array.  ProjectType.landscapes is an array and types is an array inside that array.  It's also an optional so I'm not sure how to check it.

Comment: First ask yourself. Do you really need to declare your arrays as opttional? If they will never be nil it doesnt make any sense declaring them as optional.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, they need to be optional.  They might indeed be nil.

Comment: @JohnGerard you are not showing any attempt to check uf your array is nil or not

Comment: @LeoDabus That's literally why I'm posting this question.  I'm not sure how to approach this problem at all.  I don't know how to check if an optional array is nil and I don't know how to check if it then contains a particular element.  I understand this is a basic principle, but I'm having trouble applying it here.

Comment: `if landscapes?.contains(landscape) == true {` make sure to make `Landscape` conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: @LeoDabus         if projectType.landscapes?.contains(Landscape) == true {
            Text("yes it contains landscape")
        } else {
            Text("No it does not contain landscape")
        
        }. ERROR:  Cannot convert value of type 'Landscape.Type' to expected argument type '(Landscape) throws -> Bool'. ERROR:  Missing argument label 'where:' in call

Comment: You need to pass a landscape instance. If you just want to check if it is not empty just change `contains` to `isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

first, you can use 'optional binding' methods like ' if let' or 'guard let' or simply using array count to make sure your array has a value.
after that you can use several options on Array like 'contains(_:)'
[apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains)

```
if let landScapes = project.landscapes {
    if landScapes.contains(where: {$0.mulching != nil}) {
    
}
```

}

Comment: Can you write an example using the data structure above?

Comment: @soroush_araste. if I try: "  if ((projectType.landscapes?.contains(where: "mulching")) != nil){
            MulchingView()
        }
          " I get this error:  Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(Landscape) throws -> Bool'

Comment: if let landScapes = project.landscapes {
    if landScapes.contains(where: {$0.mulching != nil}) {
        
    }
}